# How do I store a variable inside an interface to use?

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface namely `Medicine` and I created few instances for that. let's have a look,

```
interface Medicine {

    Medicine Antibiotic = new Medicine() {

        @Override
        public int getCountOfTuberculous(QuarantineTwo quarantineTwo) {
            return quarantineTwo.tuberculous().getSize();
        }

        /**
         * Antibiotic cures the tuberculous
         *
         * @param q
         */
        @Override
        public void on(QuarantineTwo q) {

            int initialNumOfTuberculous = getCountOfTuberculous(q);
            System.out.println("Numbe of perople have Tuberculous before treated w/ Antibiotic  = " + initialNumOfTuberculous);

            q.tuberculous().changeHealthStatus(q.healthy());
        }

        @Override
        public Treatment combine(Treatment treatment) {
            return treatment.plus(this);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Antibiotic";
        }
    };

    Medicine Insulin = new Medicine() {

        // cant use this method as it will provide the number of Tuberculous 0
        // because, initially, the Quarantine was treated with Antibiotic 
        @Override
        public int getCountOfTuberculous(QuarantineTwo quarantineTwo) {
            return quarantineTwo.tuberculous().getSize();
        }

        @Override
        public void on(QuarantineTwo q) {

            if (isInsulinCombinedWithAntibiotic(q.getTreatment())) {
                q.healthy().changeHealthStatus(q.feverish());
//                q.healthy().changeHealthStatus(q.feverish(), iniNumOfTuberculous);
            } else {
                // Prevent None effects, done is this.combine
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Treatment combine(Treatment treatment) {
            return treatment.remove(Medicine.None)
                    .plus(this);
        }

        /**
         * helper method to see whether the Insulin is combined with Antibiotic
         *
         * @param treatment
         * @return
         */
        private boolean isInsulinCombinedWithAntibiotic(Treatment treatment) {
            return treatment.contains(this) &&
                    treatment.contains(Medicine.Antibiotic);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Insulin";
        }
    };

    void on(QuarantineTwo quarantineTwo);
    Treatment combine(Treatment treatment); 
    int getCountOfTuberculous(QuarantineTwo quarantineTwo);
}
```

Now, when I'm testing I may call like this,

```
    @Test
    public void antibioticPlusInsulin() throws Exception {
        quarantine.antibiotic();
        quarantine.insulin();
        assertEquals("F:3 H:1 D:3 T:0 X:0", quarantine.report());
    }
```

The two lines of codes means that we combined the treatment procedures with both the antibiotic and insulin to the Quarantine system and affect should be accumulative.

```
        quarantine.antibiotic();
        quarantine.insulin();
```

And, hence, I would like to keep a track of how many people are cured with `Antibiotic` initially from the Tuberculous stored in the  `initialNumOfTuberculous` and use that  value to make the call

`q.healthy().changeHealthStatus(q.feverish(), iniNumOfTuberculous);`
This call suppose to change the all the people from healthy state to feverish but the ones initially cured with Tuberculous.

How to store the value of the `iniNumOfTuberculous` inside the `Medicine Antibiotic` and make it available in the `Medicine Insulin` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need an abstract class

```
abstract class AbstractMedicine implements Medicine {
    protected int iniNumOfTuberculous;
}
```

```
public class Insulin extends AbstractMedicine {
    // can use iniNumOfTuberculous here
}
```

Note: The availability of the variable definition is shared; the value itself is not.

I don't think you should implement your concrete classes inside an interface, by the way

Comment: I believe this is great idea as the code is getting cluttered and I really ned to write the different medicines in the separates classes. I will Implement this soon and update this reply.

Comment: Just be aware that you can only extend one class in Java. If you end up with anything more complex, a database might be your best option

Comment: Thanks I know that 